# Python loop calculate time difference

Tags: for-loop, parsing, time, difference, calculation

I have the following data

```
data = {'timestamp': ['Friday, October 15, 2021 3:40 PM', 'Oct 15, 2021 03:06:29 PM', 'Friday, October 15, 2021 2:28 PM', 'Oct 15, 2021 06:23:51 AM', 'Oct 15, 2021 04:19:07 AM', 'Oct 15, 2021 08:19:07 AM'],
        'emailuser': ['michael@google.com', 'caron@yt.com', 'luke@yt.com', 'sav@google.com','sav@google.com', 'paul@yt.com']
        }
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)
```

I would like to calculate the average time response by employees from Google. So in this case, I would want to get the time difference between

1. michael@google.com - luke@yt.com (be able to skip the timestamp from caron@yt.com because caron and luke is in the same company)
2. sav@google.com - paul@yt.com to be ignored, because it results in a negative time difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not pretty, but this should be according to the specs. Please comment if you have any questions or if you see any deviations from the specs.

**Code**

```py
import datetime

import pandas as pd

data = {
    "timestamp": [
        "Friday, October 15, 2021 3:40 PM",
        "Oct 15, 2021 03:06:29 PM",
        "Friday, October 15, 2021 2:28 PM",
        "Oct 15, 2021 06:23:51 AM",
        "Oct 15, 2021 04:19:07 AM",
        "Oct 15, 2021 08:19:07 AM",
    ],
    "emailuser": [
        "michael@google.com",
        "caron@yt.com",
        "luke@yt.com",
        "sav@google.com",
        "sav@google.com",
        "paul@yt.com",
    ],
}


def extract_datetime(timestamp: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    for format in ["%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p", "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"]:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, format)
        except:
            pass
    raise ValueError(f"Timestamp {timestamp} is invalid")


data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data["timestamp"] = data["timestamp"].apply(extract_datetime)
data["delta"] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)
gem = "@google.com"
for i in data.index:
    if data["emailuser"].iat[i][-len(gem) :] == gem:
        for j in range(i+1, data.index[-1]):
            if data["emailuser"].iat[j][-len(gem) :] != gem:
                delta = data["timestamp"].iat[i] - data["timestamp"].iat[j]
                if delta > datetime.timedelta(0):
                    data["delta"].iat[i] = delta
            else:
                break


print(data)
```

**Output**

```
            timestamp           emailuser           delta
0 2021-10-15 15:40:00  michael@google.com 0 days 01:12:00
1 2021-10-15 15:06:29        caron@yt.com 0 days 00:00:00
2 2021-10-15 14:28:00         luke@yt.com 0 days 00:00:00
3 2021-10-15 06:23:51      sav@google.com 0 days 00:00:00
4 2021-10-15 04:19:07      sav@google.com 0 days 00:00:00
5 2021-10-15 08:19:07         paul@yt.com 0 days 00:00:00
```